# Plastic SCM's cm listlocks says "The selected changeset doesn't contain a revision for the item" and does nothing. What's going wrong?

Tags: plasticscm

I'm trying to steal an exclusive lock from a user who has left our organization. From the documentation it looks like I should do this to list all the locks that are out:

```
cm listlocks MyServer@Cloud
```

Which should list a bunch of lock ids that I can use in conjuction with cm unlock. Unfortunately that command only says:

> The selected changeset doesn't contain a revision for the item

And nothing else. How do I get lock IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually figured this out. The [repsvr_spec] argument to listlocks works differently than all the other cm commands, and you need to use the --server= flag to specify the server. So the correct format is:

```
cm listlocks --server=MyOrganization@Cloud
cm unlock MyOrganization@Cloud <guid>
```